# Azure websites publish runs migrations great but my published site is throwing 500 errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I am following this tutorial:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/

On my local Visual Studio I can Build and Debug the application and create users. I can also migrate no problems.

So I published it making sure to select my database and selecting Enable Migrations. Well the migrations work perfectly. I opened my database in SQL Management Studio and it my tables are there. BUT! When I create a user on the deployed site all I get is a 500 error.

I am not sure how to figure out what is going on. All works great on my local Visual Studio (creating users). But not when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this sites and found out my connection string had a mismatched password.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#remotedebug